# How do I create an embeddable Android component that 3rd-party applications can use?

Tags: java, android

For example it could be some kind of special browser, viewer, mapping, input method, or other similar component (that probably extends SurfaceView or something similar) but I want 3rd-party developers to be able to embed it using an API that I publish *without* distributing a .jar or Java source to them, and have them be able to call its public functions, create handlers for events, and so on.

I don't want to distribute a .jar because I want to be able to independently make improvements to this viewer component (without breaking the API that I specify); there would exist only one copy on the user's system. If I distributed a .jar to people, they'd have to update their applications every time I make an improvement, which is not what I want.

Is there a sort of "hello world" explanation somewhere of how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is generally impossible, and certainly is impossible for anything of the complexity that you are describing.

You are welcome to explore the use of `RemoteViews` for sending a UI definition via some form of IPC (e.g., extra on a broadcast `Intent`). That is what app widgets use, for example. However, you cannot implement a "browser, viewer, mapping, input method, or other similar component" (except perhaps for a trivial definition of "viewer"), you cannot use `SurfaceView`, etc.